# How to add Promises in readFile function in node js

Tags: node.js

```
fs.readFile(answer, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                    var dataArray = data.split(/\r?\n/).filter(entry => entry.trim() != '');
                 console.log(dataArray);  // **Line 1**
                 });
                 console.log(dataArray);  // **Line2**
        }
```

Above code line 2 executed first then line 1 executed

Answer (score 1):

You can use readFileSync for achieving synchronousy.

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(answer, 'utf8');
var dataArray = data.split(/\r?\n/).filter(entry => entry.trim() != '');
console.log(dataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function readFilePromisified(file) {
   return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
         if (err) {
            reject(err);
         } 
         const dataArray = data.split(/\r?\n/).filter(entry => entry.trim() != '');
         console.log(dataArray);  // **Line 1**
         resolve(dataArray);

      });

   });

}
```

You can then use `async/await` :

```
( async () => {
   const dataArray = await readFilePromisified(file); // this will print **Line 1** before it returns
   console.log(dataArray); **Line 2**
})();
```